# Deepcopy issue in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that works well in Python 2.7, but fails in Python 3.4

```
newobj = copy.deepcopy(self.locale.numbers)
newobj.symbols= {'decimal': ',', 'group':' '}
return newobj.getFormatter('currency')
```

The unit test that tests this piece of code return this error in Python 3.4

```
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:155: in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:246: in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:182: in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:300: in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:155: in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:246: in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:182: in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/copy.py:301: in _reconstruct
    if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zope/i18n/locales/inheritance.py:116: in __getattr__
    selfUp = self.getInheritedSelf()
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zope/i18n/locales/__init__.py:670: in getInheritedSelf
    language = self.id.language
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zope/i18n/locales/inheritance.py:116: in __getattr__
    selfUp = self.getInheritedSelf()
.tox/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/zope/i18n/locales/__init__.py:670: in getInheritedSelf
    language = self.id.language
!!! Recursion detected (same locals & position)
```

How do I solve this for both Python versions?

Comment: what is the code copying?

Comment: I think without seeing what you are copying it is going to be hard to answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - it's this object - <zope.i18n.locales.LocaleNumbers object>   - http://docs.zope.org/zope3/Code/zope/i18n/locales/LocaleNumbers.1.  Does that help?